# Como clonar array

Tags: javascript, array, slice

Estou perambulando sobre um meio de fazer com que, ao findar todos elementos da `array` em questão, voltar tudo de novo.

Veja este meu código-fonte abaixo:

## Código

```
<html>

<body>

    <button onclick="next()">APAGAR</button>

</body>

<script>
var total = 4,
    letras = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];

function next() {
    // Antes de começar a apagar o primeiro indice, conferir se array
    // está totalmente vazio e popular array novamente caso positivo
    if (total.length === 0) {
        // Para popular a array use
        total = letras.slice(0);
    }
    // A cada clique, eliminar o elemento [0]
    var indice = letras.splice(0, 1);
    alert(indice, letras);
}
</script>

</html>
```

Mas quando ele chega ao fim, não retorna o que necessito. Seria voltar tudo de novo como de início. Tipo uma roleta.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, você quer remover o primeiro elemento do array toda vez que se clicar no botão e retornar o array sem esse elemento?

Comment: @GabrielC. Ele ja esta removendo. Agora preciso que ele detecte que a `array` estando vazia voltar a populacionar ela novamente com elementos dela mesma. Por isso que coloquei no titulo "clone".

Comment: então porque você está inicializando a varável `total` com o valor `4`, sendo que depois está checando a propriedade `length`? Desse modo a condicional não será `true` já que `total.length` retornará `undefined`

Comment: @GabrielC. Em outra ocasião não havia definido esta variável `total` deste modo. Em outro teste havia atribuído assim `var total, link = [ .. ]`, mas no console acusava que não estava definida a variável `total`. Portanto decidi fazer essa mudança, pra ver se dava.

Comment: @GabrielC. Sei que estou no rumo certo, pois o método `slice` retorna uma cópia de um `array` em um novo objeto `array`. Só não estou conseguindo finalizar esta etapa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode reduzir o valor de `total` em `1` toda vez que um elemento for removido, além do mais, crie um `array` chamado original para que ele possa ser clonado pelo `array` letras.Desse modo, quando total atingir 0, você repopula o `array` e reseta o valor de `total`. Veja como o código fica:

```
 var total = 4, original = [ "A", "B", "C", "D" ], letras = [ "A", "B", "C",
        "D" ];

function next() {
    // Antes de começar a apagar o primeiro indice, conferir se array
    // está totalmente vazio e popular array novamente caso positivo
    if (total === 0) {
        // Para popular a array use
        alert("clonando");
        letras = original.slice(0);
        //reseta o valor de total
        total = 4;
    }
    // A cada clique, eliminar o elemento [0]
    var indice = letras.splice(0, 1);
    alert(indice);
    alert(letras);
        total -= 1;
    }
```

Comment: @DiegoHenrique fiz uma pequena edição, então espero que você tenha copiado a parte onde se reseta o valor de `total`